# number beside a string php

Tags: php, arrays

i have a string "9 bedrooms in that house", but it could be anything else, but bedroom keywords will stay (bed, beds, bedrooms, bedroom, etc.) <- this is $search_array variable

i have converted it into an array using explode

i need to find a word bedroom and to see if there is a number beside it.

assuming my array after explode is - (9, bedrooms, in, that, house), how can i check for a number beside it

i have used that code below and its inside a function hence $array =& $this->search_array

```
if($array =& $this->search_array){
$bedroom_keywords = array('bed', 'beds', 'bedroom', 'bedrooms');
foreach($this->bedroom_keywords as $beds)
        {   
            // if successful in assigning key find a 
            // number in next and previous positions
            if($key = array_search($beds, $array))
            {
                if($next = $array[$key+1])
                {
                    echo $next;
                }
                elseif($prev = $array[$key-1])
                {
                    echo $prev;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

but im getting this error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Users/User/Sites/parser.php on line 92 9ad_type:

when i use just 2 tokens ie - "9 beds".

is there any way i can check if there is a next/previous value in the array or do something so it'll work?

thanks

Comment: Note that `=` is not equal to `==`

Comment: ..and that `private` is a class variable, and not something you should use to initiate a variable inside a function.

Comment: This sounds like it should be solved with a regular expression. What is your final aim here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for this task:

```
([0-9]+) +(bed|beds|bedroom|bedrooms)
```

will find a number with at lease one digit, then any number of spaces, then one of those bed words.

Comment: Number can be on both sides :)

Comment: You did not specify that ... anyway, try `(bed|beds|bedroom|bedrooms) +([0-9]*)` if first regex did not match.

Comment: @arnep well he said "beside" it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check the length of your array, because when you run the function on "9 beds", key+1 will be 2, and the array only has the positions 0 and 1. You can just add a condition to your inner if-else conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression. For example, to get the number of beds from each input:

```
$inputs = array('1 bed', '22 beds', '1 bedROOM', '99   beDRooms', 'beds');
foreach($inputs as $input) {
    if (preg_match('/(\d+)\s+bed($|s|room|rooms)/i', $input, $matches)) {
        echo "$input => ".$matches[1]."\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "$input => **no match**\n";
    }
}
```

The regex above matches one or more digits (which we want to isolate) followed by any amount of whitespace, followed by any of the trigger words you mention.

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/VVHRu).

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have array

`$bedroom_keywords = array('bed', 'beds', 'bedroom', 'bedrooms');`

and you want to check key word, this is also you can do

```
foreach($bedroom_keywords as $keyword){
    // here you will check it from you actuall array
     if(in_array($keyword ,'yoyr array')){
         echo 'success';
    }
}
```

hope this wil help